# how to embed the video in such way that the paragraph will continue on top of it after the video is moved down?

Tags: css, video, embed, paragraph

Does anyone know how to embed a video (which is floated to the right of the screen) in a such way, that the paragraph will continue on top of it after it is moved down? [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zw3XL.png)

```
.video {
    border-image:url(box.png) 20 20 round;
            border-width: 20px; 
            float:right;
            margin-top: 100px;
            margin-bottom: 0 px;

<span class="video"><object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" style="width:420px; height:240px;" data="http://www.youtube.com/v/zOETaUx3c4o?color2=FBE9EC&amp;version=3">
        <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/zOETaUx3c4o?color2=FBE9EC&amp;version=3" />
        <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" />
        <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always" />
        </object><br/><div style="text-align: center; font-size: 12px; font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode; ">Flag Alphabet<br/>by <a href="http://www.youtube.com/user/LearnFree2007?feature=watch">LearnFree2007</a></div></div>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting `wmode="transparent"` or `wmode="opaque"` as an attribute in the object tag? Videos such as those from Youtube end up always on top because they default to `wmode="window"` when the attribute is not set.